# Applications changing screen color temps

Tags: windows-10

I have noticed that Adobe Reader DC and Office 2016 change the color temp of the screen when opened, the screen immediately returns to normal when they are closed.

It is as if they are activating *Night Light* mode in Windows 10. I have turned off this setting in the control panel but the issue persists.

Does anybody know how to stop/block this behavior or what might be causing it?

Thanks